# How can I find where FK = PK in the same table?

Tags: mysql

I have one table named `employees` which contains employees' IDs (which is PK)-stands for managers-and reportsTo(which is FK). I don't know what is the correct condition to find which manager is being reported to by their employees? I've tried this condition but it didn't work

```
select 
   employeeNumber, 
   lastName, 
   phone, 
   extension 
from employees 
where reportsTo = employeeNumber
```

I'm new to mysql!
[Here is my table](http://collabedit.com/a8fhm)
Thank you.

Comment: [Help me write this query in SQL](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977)

Comment: I think your looking for a [recursive cte](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mysql-recursive-cte-common-table-expressions/)